# Different memory usage on different devices

Tags: memory, libgdx

I am creating a LibGDX based game and load assets with the Assetmanager.
All packed with Texturepacker.

For example level 1 has 96 pics with 9.78 mb disk space usage.
Level 2 has 226 pics with 17,4 mb disk space usage, not sifficant more.

I tested the game on Sony Z2 (Andoid 6) and Samsung Galaxy s7 (Android 7)

Now level 1 use on both devices ca. 140 mb RAM.
And level 2 use on s7 ca 90 mb and on Z2 600 mb.

How can it be that the older Phone use so much more RAM.
The GC should be the same or not?

Has anyone an idea?

Thank´s for helping.

By the way,: Know everyone why the assets on drive use just 10 mb and ingame 120 mb?
Would be nice to know

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect the GC on two different Android versions to behave identically. Nor on two different phones, even with the same version of Android.

Regarding your second question, image assets that you have saved as PNG or JPG are compressed, but OpenGL loads them uncompressed, so they take up a lot more RAM than the source files. A typical color image takes up four bytes of RAM per pixel, regardless of the source image size.

If you are really using too much RAM, you can look at using ETC1 compressed images, which stay compressed even after they are loaded. The downside besides the image degradation is that it doesn't work for images with any alpha transparency. Instructions are [here in the LibGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-Compression).